# How to do batched writes in firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, atomic

I'm making a social media app, and I need to be able to do multiple sets, updates, and deletes at the same time. And they need to either all succeed or all fail.

I know in firestore you can do a batched write, but I can't find how to do it with realtime database.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect of a batched write but in realtime database?

I tried googling it and haven't found anything.

Comment: I did a web search for "stack overflow firebase realtime database batch write" and found the duplicates.